# C++ error: initializer element is not constant

Tags: c++

I can't get this simple C++ code to work:

```
int secInt = 5;

double rubbish = secInt/60;

double factor = floor(rubbish);
```

I always get "**ERROR: initializer element is not constant**"  from line 3

Factor always returns 0.00  in the log

Could anyone help with this, I'm feeling that I overlooked something very simple.

An example of this error can be seen here: http://ideone.com/2Wrkr9

Comment: [We need more details.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b1b426664b346fda84a75d0adf7f0e12-1b036ecaef78454f1d9f193334136cf5) Where did the error come from?

Comment: updated the question, line 3

Comment: did u `#include <math.h>` ?

Comment: In your code `rubbish` is always 0. Because 'secInt/60' is integer arithmentics. You need to cast at least one of the arguments to `double`: i.e `secInt/60.` (note the dot).

Comment: The question is tagged as `C++`, but example is `Objective-C`... Compile it as C++.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk i did, and it still doesn't work, refer to the linked example

Comment: It compiles fine under visual studio 2012 c++

Comment: okay it does work in C++ , but why not objective-c ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double rubbish = secInt/60;
```

should be

```
double rubbish = static_cast<double>(secInt)/60;
```

since `secInt =5`, so `floor(rubbish)` should be `0` even with the above correction.

You should have at least a `main` function if you do not have any other function in your source file. `main` is the entry point.

```
int main()
{
 int secInt = 5;
 double rubbish = static_cast<double>(secInt)/60.0;

 double factor = floor(rubbish);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: The cast is redundant as soon as you turn `60` into `60.0`.

Comment: @NathanErnst agreed, cast one of them is enough. thanks, post updated.

Comment: No worries, just being pedantic.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be inside the `main` portion of your program:

```
int main()
{
    int secInt = 583;

    double rubbish = secInt/60.0;

    double factor = floor(rubbish);
}
```

You should also use standard C++ headers like `<cmath>`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to enclose the code in a function.

Try this.

```
int main()
{
    int secInt = 5;

    double rubbish = secInt/60.0;

    double factor = floor(rubbish);
}
```

C++ will begin executing code in the function named `main`, and from there, call whatever functions are called from main.